# Python Server Pages, Session Timeout Set

Tags: python, http, session-timeout, mod-python

Real easy one for those Python Server Pages guru's

```
<%
user_session = Session.Session(req)
user_session['username'] = varUsername
user_session['fullname'] = varFullName
%>
```

The Session seems to timeout after a short amount of time. How can I set the Session timeout to be 1 hour?

**Additions**:
This is not a server session timeout, but a code session timeout. Specifically within mod-python....

Answer (score 0):

```
user_session.set_timeout(3600)
```

Works for me.